# How bad pattern of using promises to make async call of FSM methods?

Tags: javascript, promise

What if I have two tiny fsm and want make communication between them.
In communication process may occur chain of calls like

`A.first(B.first(A.second(B.second)))` to break this chain I want to use promises to make async function calls like in code beneath.

```
function FirstTinyFSM() {
    this.state = 'ready';
}

FirstTinyFSM.prototype.a = function(data) {
    ...
    //process data 
};

FirstTinyFSM.prototype.start = function() {
    global_event_emiter.on('some event', this.process_some_event.bind(this));
};

FirstTinyFSM.prototype.process_some_event = function() {

    Promise.resolve(1).then(function(){
        second.b('some data');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // handle errors
    });
};

function SecondTinyFSM() {
    this.state = 'ready';
}

SecondTinyFSM.prototype.b = function(data) {
    ...

    // process data
    Promise.resolve(1).then(function(){
        first.a('some data');
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // handle errors
    });
};

first = new FirstTinyFSM();
second = new SecondTinyFSM();

first.start();
```

How this pattern is bad? What other options I have?

Comment: You'll want to have a look at CSP.

Comment: I have no idea what exactly you are doing here, but you'll want to `return` promises from your `then` callbacks generally.